# Show $x^2+4x+18\equiv 0\pmod{49}$ has no solution

Tags: elementary-number-theory

My method was to just complete the square:

$x^2+4x+18\equiv 0\pmod{49}$

$(x+2)^2\equiv -14\pmod{49}$

$x+2\equiv \sqrt{35}\pmod{49}$

So $x\equiv\sqrt{35}-2\pmod{49}$, which has no real solutions.

---

I feel that this may be too elementary, is this the correct way to solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed, it is wrong. $49 \mid (x+2)^2+14$ implies $7\mid (x+2)^2$, and in particular $7\mid x+2$. But this means that $49\mid (x+2)^2$, and by difference $49$ should divide $14$ too, which is false.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't elegant, but it doesn't take that long. Suppose, for contradiction, that there is a solution modulo $49$. In order for there to be a solution modulo $49$, there must be a solution modulo $7$.

$$x^2+4x+4\equiv \begin{cases}
4  \pmod{7} &\mbox{if } x \equiv 0 \pmod{7}\\
2  \pmod{7} &\mbox{if } x \equiv 1 \pmod{7}\\
2  \pmod{7} &\mbox{if } x \equiv 2 \pmod{7}\\
4  \pmod{7} &\mbox{if } x \equiv 3 \pmod{7}\\
1  \pmod{7} &\mbox{if } x \equiv 4 \pmod{7}\\
0  \pmod{7} &\mbox{if } x \equiv 5 \pmod{7}\\
1  \pmod{7} &\mbox{if } x \equiv 6 \pmod{7}\\
\end{cases}
$$

Now, following Paolo Leonetti, if $x \equiv 5 \equiv -2 \pmod{7}$, then $$x^2+4x+4 \equiv 0 \pmod{49}$$

But this, along with our original equivalence, gives the ridiculous conclusion

$$14 \equiv (x^2+4x+18)-(x^2+4x+4)\equiv 0 \pmod{49}$$

Comment: It is correct. But you still have to check at least other 7 cases by hand, namely all $x=7k+5$ modulo $49$ :)

Comment: Hensel's lemma is used to prove the existence (and uniqueness) of a solution, here modulo $49$. And it is not surprising that it is does not apply. Check why ;)

Comment: You are right. $2(5)+4 \equiv 0 \pmod{7}$. Clearly my proof was wrong.

Comment: Well, it is true that, if a solution exists, then $7\mid x-5$, and from here you could do seven cases by hand; nevertheless, it is almost the same to say "there are just 49 classes of residue, and we can solve the problem in O(1) operations" :P

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti But are you sure there is no quick way? I started doing them by hand and realized they were *all* equal to $14$ mod $49$, so there is probably a reason ...

Comment: Seeing my solution, you see in a moment why they are all $14$ modulo $49$ ;)

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti Nice, +1

Comment: What do you mean by "Paolo Leonetti"?

Comment: The user "jordan" used to have the username "Paolo Leonetti"

Answer (score 1):

You are right, except the symbol $\sqrt{35}$ is not very good notation modulo $p$ because there is no way to distinguish between the two possible roots. Also, just because the number $35$ doesn't have a real square root doesn't automatically imply that it doesn't have one modulo $49$. For example, the number 7 has no real square root, but it is a square modulo $9$.

Here's how I would rewrite your proof.

Suppose that $x^2 + 4x + 18 \equiv 0$ had a solution mod $49$. Then, completing the square, we see that $(x+2)^2 \equiv 35$ has a solution mod $49$. It follows that $y^2 \equiv 35$ has a solution mod $49$.

Therefore, it suffices to show that $35$ is a non-square mod 49. Indeed, if $y^2 \equiv 35$ then $y^4 \equiv 0$. We deduce that $7 | y$, since if $7 \nmid y$ then $49 \nmid y^4$. But then $y^2 \equiv 0$, contradiction.

Comment: you mean 'no _integer_ square root'.

Answer (score 1):

$$(x+2)^2 \equiv -14 \equiv 35 \pmod{49} \text{ is solvable}$$

$$\iff (-14)^{\phi(49)/2} \equiv 35^{\phi(49)/2} \equiv 1 \pmod{49} \text { (But this is false.)}$$

**Theorem:** If $m$ is has a primitive root (2, 4, and odd prime powers), $x^k \equiv a \pmod{m}$ has a solution if and only if $$\Large a^{\frac{\phi(m)}{gcd(\phi(m),k)}} \equiv 1 \pmod{m}$$ In that case, the equation has $gcd(k, \phi(m))$ incongruent solutions.

**Another way**: $(x+2)^2 \equiv 35 \pmod{49} \implies (x+2)^2 \equiv 35 \equiv 0 \pmod{7}$
$\implies (x+2)^2 \equiv 0 \pmod{49} \text{ (contradiction)}$

**One more way**: Use Hensel's lemma to solve for $\text{(some polynomial)} \equiv 0 \pmod{prime^k}$.

Comment: $2p^k$ ($p$ odd prime) has a primitive root too. $m$ has a primitive root iff (if and only if) $m=2,4,p^k, 2p^k$, where $p$ is an odd prime.

Comment: Where can I find a proof of the $\gcd(\phi(m),k)$ theorem?